# Selecting HTML Content of a node LINQ XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML like this

```
  <component>
        <section>
          <title>Reporting Parameters</title>
          <text>
            <list>
              <item>Reporting period: January 1st, 2012
            </list>
          </text>
       </section>
   </component>
```

I want to select entire content of  node including   etc. elements but it selects only plain text "Reporting period: January 1st, 2012" , Reason is that it might content some HTML markup which I need to store in database, I am using following query

```
  var components = (from c in cdafile.Root.Elements(ns + "component")
                  select new{
                      name = (string)c.Element(ns + "section").Element(ns + "title").Value,
                      text = (string)c.Element(ns + "section").Element(ns + "text"),
                  });
```

Comment: If this is actual HTML (your item tag has no ending tag), then you should try HTML Agility Pack to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit cast operator is overloaded for `XElement` ([to return concatenated, inner text of nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx)), use `.ToString()` to get nodes content:

```
text = c.Element(ns + "section").Element(ns + "text").ToString()
```

And to get children markup *only*:

```
text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, c
    .Element(ns + "section").Element(ns + "text")
    .Elements().Select(e => e.ToString())
)
```

Comment: @PitDigger: to do that you need to combine all children's `.ToString` into one string, say via `string.Join` - see my edit.